# How find this function $f(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous such that $\dfrac{f(x)}{x}=f'\left(\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$. Find  $f(x)$.

(2):if $f(x)$ on $x\in[a,b] $ be continuous,find all $f(x)$?

I think this is an ODE.

Comment: yes,Thank you @julien,

Comment: The analytic solutions with radius $+\infty$ are $f(x)=Cx+Dx^2$ for some constants $C,D$.

Comment: why,@julien,Thank you my frend.

Comment: **Hint:** $f(1)=f'(\dfrac{1}{2})$,

$f(2)=2f'(1)$

.

.

.

$f(2^{n-1})=2^{n-1} \cdot f'(2^{n-2})$.....


$f(2^n)=2^n \cdot f'(2^{n-1})$

Comment: @Inceptio What can we deduce from that?

Comment: oh,Thank you ,@julien,But I have other question, if $f(x)$ in$[a,b]$ is continuous, where $a,b$ is constants, then $f(x)$ must $f(x)=c_{1}x+c_{2}x^2$? Thank you

Comment: @julien: Thinking. (That's why it isn't an answer)

Comment: @math110 You're not done...This only gives the power series solutions with infinite radius of convergence. The same applies to intervals $(-a,a)$ for power series solutions with radius $\geq a$. Other than that...

Comment: @julien why do you start with the assumption that the solution is a polynomial?

Comment: @ZettaSuro No. I just said that the power series solutions with infinite radius are $Cx+Dx^2$. That's better than nothing, and that is fairly natural. I never said that it solves the problem completely.

Comment: @math110 How did you come across this problem? Context might provide a more suitable solution and avoid overkills.

Comment: This problem is my frend (Math competition player)
ask me, @GitGud

Comment: The main problem seems to be: Is $f(0)=0$? Does $f'(0)$ exist?

Comment: look for some time,I have find this problem similar this:http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=383299&sid=e7b356f4d3d4254acb846856a7c6b70c#p383299

Comment: @GitGud What Hagen von Eitzen points at is that the equation is for $x\neq 0$. So it does not, even implicitly, say that $f'(0)$ exists.

Comment: @julien I had totally forgoton about the $x$ in the denominator.

Comment: if $f'(a/x)=\dfrac{x}{f(x)}$,we have $$f(a/x)f'(x)=a/x$$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen As you say this seems to be the main problem, do you know what to do with the extra assumption that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)$ exists? I don't, outside of power series.

Comment: @julien After seeing Achille hui's solution, I notice that my attempt was a dead end ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\alpha_0 = 1, \alpha_1 = 2$ and let $\alpha_2, \alpha_3, \ldots$ be the complete set of roots in the complex plane of the equation:

$$\alpha = 2^{\alpha-1}  \quad\text{ subject to constraint }\quad \Re{\alpha} > 1, \Im{\alpha} > 0$$

For $k \ge 2$, write $\alpha_k$ as $\beta_k + \gamma_k i$ where $\beta_k, \gamma_k \in \mathbb{R}$.

For any set of real constants $A_0, A_1, \ldots$ and $\delta_2, \delta_3, \ldots \in \mathbb{R}$. It is easy to check the function defined by:

$$\begin{align}f(x) 
&= A_0 x + A_1 x^2 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \Re{\left( A_k e^{i\delta_k} x^{\alpha_k}\right)}\\
&= A_0 x + A_1 x^2 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} A_k x^{\beta_k} \cos(\gamma_k\log(x) + \delta_k)
\end{align}$$

is a solution of the functional equation over $[0,\infty)$ provided this series and the series associated with its derivative converge.

The condition $\Re{\alpha_k} > 1$ for $k \ge 2$ ensure $f(x)$ falls off to zero fast enough so that $f'(0+)$ is defined and equal to $A_0$.

Over $(-\infty,0]$, we can define another function $\tilde{f}(x)$ in a similar manner:

$$\begin{align}\tilde{f}(x) 
&= \tilde{A}_0 x + \tilde{A}_1 x^2 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \Re{\left( \tilde{A}_k e^{i\tilde{\delta}_k} |x|^{\alpha_k}\right)}\\
&= \tilde{A}_0 x + \tilde{A}_1 x^2 + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \tilde{A}_k |x|^{\beta_k} \cos(\gamma_k\log|x| + \tilde{\delta}_k)
\end{align}$$

Once again, this is a solution for the functional equation over $(-\infty,0]$ provided
this series and the series associated with its derivative converge. Furthermore, 
$f'(0-)$ exists and equal to $\tilde{A}_0$.

If $A_0 = \tilde{A}_0$, we can paste this two solution together to construct a $C^{1}$ solution of the functional equation over whole $\mathbb{R}$.

For an example, $\alpha_2 \sim 4.545364930374021 + 10.75397517526888 i$ implies
$$f(x) \sim |x|^{4.545364930374021} \cos(10.75397517526888 \log|x|)$$
will be a non-trivial $C^1$ solution for the functional equation.

[image: Solution associated with alpha_2]

Comment: You're really good at constructing nontrivial solutions, +1.